# Override Jade script. block

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pug

I'm trying override a Jade `script.` tag,but all what I do don't work.

I have the following code:

Layout.jade

```
    block foot
    footer.container#footer
        .row
            .twelve.columns Todos os direitos reservados. &copy; 2015 Pet Feeder

block scripts
    script(src="/javascripts/js/jquery.min.js")
    script(src="/javascripts/lib/jQueryUI/jquery-ui-1.8.18.custom.min.js")
    script(src="/javascripts/js/s_scripts.js")
    script(src="/javascripts/js/jquery.ui.extend.js")
    script(src="/javascripts/lib/qtip2/jquery.qtip.min.js")
    script(src="/javascripts/lib/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.min.js")
    script(src="/javascripts/js/jquery.list.min.js")
    script(src="/javascripts/js/pertho.js")

script.
    $(document).ready(function(){
        prth_common.init();         
    });
```

Until here,everything is fine,and the script runs like a charm. But when I need put another script,from other views,the `script.` added from the view doesn't work. They simply doesn't get added.

anyView.jade

```
block content
//my content here    
script.
function sendForm(){
$.ajax({
    url:'/some/controller',
    data:$("#form_save").serialize(),
    type:'POST',
    dataType:'JSON',
    beforeSend:function(){
      //some stuff here
    },
    success:function(data){
      console.log(data);
    }
  });
}
$("#submit_form").click(function(){
  sendForm();
});
```

How can I do that?

EDIT - the full files:

https://gist.github.com/sp4rtablood/e59075d52d594cbaa4bf

https://gist.github.com/sp4rtablood/f0d6d83aa93be9773b85

Comment: Every tag needs to have its content **indented**. Your content under your `script.` isn't indented.

Comment: So,if I put the `script.` indented along with the `block content` it will be placed inside of him and before the external scripts (`block script`) and the footer .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a view `extends` another, it no longer allows for loose content. The `script.` in `anyView.jade` is being discarded as invalid.

[It's expected to be placed under a `block`](http://jade-lang.com/reference/inheritance/), such as `scripts`. You can use `append` to insert it after `script(src="/javascripts/js/pertho.js")`:

```
extends layout

block content
    # ...

block append scripts
    script.
        function sendForm(){
            // ...
        }
        $("#submit_form").click(function(){
          sendForm();
        });
```

That should generate:

```
<!-- ... -->
<script src="/javascripts/js/pertho.js"></script>
<script>
        function sendForm(){
            // ...
        }
        $("#submit_form").click(function(){
          sendForm();
        });
</script>
<!-- ... -->
```

Comment: Great! It's exactly what I need. Thanks by the explanation too.